# Quickly generate junk data of certain size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamically-generated

I am writing an upload speed test in Javascript.  I am using Jquery (and Ajax) to send chunks of data to a server in order to time how long it takes to get a response.  This should, in theory give an estimation, of the upload speed.

Of course to cater for different bandwidths of the user I sequentially upload larger and larger amounts of junk data until a threshold duration is reached.  Currently I generate the junk data using the following function, however, it is very slow when generation megabytes of data.

```
function generate_random_data(size){
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var random_data = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++){
        var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);
        random_data = random_data + chars.substring(random_num,random_num+1);
    }
    return random_data;
}
```

Really all I am doing is generating a chunk of bytes to send to the server, however, this is the only way I could find out how in Javascript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
I have re-written my code to make it just a repetition of a 10 byte string instead of a completely random string.

```
function generate_random_data(attempt){
    var table = {
        '1':10, //10kb  
        '2':12, //40kb
        '3':14, //160kb
        '4':16, //640kb
        '5':18, //2.5Mb
        '6':20 //10Mb
    }
    var random_data = "abcdefghij";  //10 bytes
    for (i = 0; i < table[attempt]; i++){
        random_data += random_data;
    }
    return random_data;
```

Now the function takes an argument of the attempt number (so the first time my script tries to upload it'll do the smallest file, then the next smallest, so-on and so-forth).  It then gets a 10 byte string and then keeps adding it to itself until the desired length is reached.

Is this the best way?  Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think  you need to generate random characters for this purpose, no?

Comment: Use something like [lipsum.com](http://www.lipsum.com/) to generate a chunk of text, then just keep doubling it. If you really want randomness, put several paragraphs in an array and chose them randomly instead of individual characters. Should be good enough.

Comment: I will check that out.
@SiGanteng You are right, I don't need 'random' data as such, or even 'junk' data.  I just need something of a specific size to send.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to generate data to upload, and don't care about it being *random*, there is a way to do it using a `Blob` object

```
// Size should be given in 'bytes'
function generate_random_data(size) {
    return new Blob([new ArrayBuffer(size)], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
};
```

I recently used this to test my upload speed against `http://httpbin.org/post`

Comment: You are creating a Blob from an initialised ArrayBuffer.  All octets will be 0x00, ie: not random.  You could call your function `generate_static_data` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something like [the answer from Jose Arandi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024734/10380981) but for NodeJS, you can use [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer).

`Buffer.alloc(10)` gives you 10 zero bytes. `Buffer.allocUnsafe(10)` does not initialize the buffer, giving you 10 "random" bytes.

Comment: Note that there is a chance that `allocUnsafe` will return a buffer containing a database password or private user data.

Answer (score 2):

Just a comment…

The following is a lot faster in IE at least:

```
function generate_random_data1(size){
    var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    var len = chars.length;
    var random_data = [];

    while (size--) {
        random_data.push(chars[Math.random()*len | 0]);
    }

    return random_data.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable on the page with 1-100k of hardcoded data in it and then possibly concatenate a few of these chunks together. String concatenation can be pretty slow though so you'll want to test it out to see if it perform ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small thought here, why are we trying this hard that data should be random. You can try sending chunks of the chars. say if size is say 1000. you can send 'a...z' 37 times. That will speed up the generation of the data. In the end you need to send some data to check the speed and not generate random data. You can also think of including upper case and numbers in chars to further increase the speed of generating this data.

By doing this you will be able to skip all the calls to find and append characters in your random data.